# Why are my video cards leaking grease?

Tags: graphics-card

I've got a couple machines where I've noticed a greasy substance forming on various parts of the video card.  One suspect was just excess grease from the fan, but it's also forming on the back side of the cards nowhere near the splatter zone of any fans.  I'm seeing it on 2 (similar setup) machines.  In fact, one of those machines left a sizeable pool of grease in the bottom of the case (and on top of the SSD) over the weekend!

I'm really not sure if this is anything to worry about or not...

Comment: Are you sure it's grease? Pick some of with a toothpick, feel it, smell it, burn it. What do you observe? Does the card have large electrolytic capacitors? Do they look OK (no swelling/bulges)? Anything external that could have entered your PC?

Comment: Standard CPU/GPU fans do not use grease.

Comment: I would be curious to see pics of this...

Comment: My guess is it would be the bearings on the fans that leaked. However, it's rare and weird that it has happened on two devices you own. Uploading some pictures would be a good help.

Comment: Condensation combined with smoke fumes perhaps? Outside of an electrolytic capacitor or something exploding inside your machine there is nothing that can or should result in a pool of grease. Check the local environment for these machines. Are you in a workshop of any kind? Pictures would be useful here to show the location, size and broad type of material...

Comment: Dust and Grease (from cooking) collected from air e.g. in a kitchen?

Comment: Capacitors all look fine.  The machines are in a controlled environment (a small datacenter).  I'll see if I can upload some pics.